# Sencha touch displaying image within tab panel

Tags: image, model-view-controller, view, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I am trying to display an image without a tab panel in my view.js
However, it can't seem to work despite having followed the documentation. Can anyone help to point out what i have done wrong?

Thank you

App.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'hoodhelp1a',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: ['Main'],

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('hoodhelp1a.view.Main'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

View/Main.js

```
Ext.define("hoodhelp1a.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.Img',   
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
                },
                {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png'
                }
            ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Get Started',
                iconCls: 'action',

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'Getting Started'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'video',
                        url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                        posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a 'hbox' layout for your 'container' inside your first tab, you must specify the 'flex' config. (for instance, set 'flex:1' in your 'image' config).

Another option is to set the layout of this 'container' to 'fit' instead.

By the way, the 'xtype:container' is not necessary.

See this fiddle for illustration purpose:
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#X0Ejm

Comment: Thank you! That was a great help.